# How can I see which wifi channel is used by my laptop with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8.1, network-adapter, wifi-configuration

How can I see which wifi channel is used by my laptop with Windows 8 ?

Comment: Must you ping me to address something like this after 2 years?  Removed the comment to avoid noisy and unnecessary pings in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to type on cmd prompt:

`netsh wlan show all`

Comment: Perhaps see if `netsh wlan show interfaces` gives you this information (it does on Windows 10 anyway), as it's much shorter.  The `show all` subcommand to `netsh wlan` is huge.